# Is there a macOS equivalent of the Windows assoc command?

Tags: macos, terminal

I am looking to change a file association on the Mac using some sort of script. I know that I can do something like that in Windows using the `assoc`  command.

Is there something scriptable on macOS which will do a similar job?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: I'm was going to create an answer for this, explaining how the duti program performs exactly the same duty as the assoc command. However, this has now been marked as a duplicate for an answer, where I cannot add my answer, as that question requires a solution without third party software.

Comment: Have a look at: [https://github.com/moretension/duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti)

Answer (score 0):

No. Apple file mapping is implemented very differently than windows does it. The file metadata has many variables that affect launch services and mapping a particular file to a particular app.